# Running multiple projects at the same time in play framework

Tags: http, playframework, multiple-instances

I am trying to run 2 projects built using `play framework` simultaneously but with little success. This is the error that pops up while trying to run the second instance:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized 
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_E
RROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

I tried changing the `http` port of one to `9000` and the other to `9001`, but still the same error. Any ideas as to how I can get these multiple instances running ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play uses 2 ports in dev mode. One for http and one for jpda. You can change both in your application.conf file

```
http.port=9001
jpda.port=8001
```

Answer (score 1):

Bonus answer : In **production** mode, only the **http port** is used.